# Force KOMA-Script title to fill whole page

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, titles

I’m using KOMA-Script (`scrreprt`) and its excellent set of macros to define a rich title page:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\subject{Subject}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\publishers{Publishers}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this leaves rather large vertical spaces above and below the actual content (made visible by the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package).

[image: screenshot]

<sup>(Image cropped and rescaled)</sup>

This is very annoying, since now the content doesn’t align with the previous and next page. Is there a way to prevent that, i.e. stretch the title page’s content so that it touches the frame above and below?

I tried introducing a vertical space above the publishers:

```
\publishers{
  \vspace{\stretch{10000}}
  Publishers}
```

This does indeed produce the desired stretch, but no matter how large I set the stretch factor, a too large space still remains.

How can I change that, and *still* use the KOMA title page macros, *without* major rewrite?

#### What’s a “major rewrite”?!

Consider this: `\maketitle` in KOMA-Script produces up to six pages (half-title, title, title back, dedication …). I’m not opposed to rewrite the `\maketitle` macro, as long as the rewrite is along the following lines:

```
\edef\maketitle{
  \do\some\adjustments%
  \maketitle}
```

That is, re-use the existing `\maketitle` and just tweak it. I don’t want to have to produce the aforementioned six pages manually.

Comment: Define the term »major rewrite«. Would this apply to modifying the `\maketitle` command?

Comment: @Thorsten: excellent question. see the new paragraph I added to the question (“What’s a ‘major rewrite’?!”).

Comment: See also: [Remove margins for title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page/25408#25408).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change that and continue using `\maketitle`. The `\vfill` and arguments of `\vskip` are hardcoded in the definition of this macro: no option can change them or suppress them.

I guess your best bet is to do the title page yourself using the `titlepage` environment. You can still look at the definition of `\maketitle` in `scrreport.cls` (`kpsewhich` will tell you the location of this file), especially if you want to reuse the arguments of `\title` and the like (don't forget to use `\makeatletter`). Also, don't use the `center` environment since it adds vertical space, use the `\centering` command instead.

I'm aware that it probably doesn't satisfy your "without major rewrite" requirement, but there is no way to satisfy it. Sometimes even KOMA is not as  configurable as one may wish.

Comment: Pity that there’s no way to configure it. Well, for now I’m going with this approach since it’s indeed the easiest (just remove the `\vfill` and `\null` commands before and after, change `\begin{center}` into `\begingroup\centering`). I’ll switch to Stefan’s solution on the long run, though.

Answer (score 4):

KOMA-Script offers a new package called [`titlepages`](http://www.komascript.de/files/titlepage.tex), which is still in early development. For instance, it provides an environment called `fullsizetitle` which covers the whole page without being restricted by the margins. There are some blog entries of the developer providing some information in German:

- [Description](http://www.komascript.de/titlepage)
- [Installation](http://www.komascript.de/node/1213)
- [Usage](http://www.komascript.de/node/1214)
- [Examples](http://www.komascript.de/node/1219)

Perhaps have a look at the last link, at the examples page to get an impression.

Answer (score 1):

KOMA-Script classes provides option `titlepage=firstiscover` to declare the first title page to be a cover page. After that, you can change the top, left, right and bottom margins redefining the command `\coverpagetopmargin`, `\coverpageleftmargin`, `\coverpagerightmargin` and `\coverpagebottommargin`. You can even use negative value to reduce the effect of the `\null\vfill` at the begin of `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=firstiscover]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*{\coverpagetopmargin}{-.25\paperheight}
\renewcommand*{\coverpagebottommargin}{-.25\paperheight}

\subject{Subject}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\publishers{Publishers}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

would result in a title page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point. Just to clarify, though: in my case, I really wanted a *title* page, not a cover page. The cover in that case was typeset in a separate document.