# Remove margins for title page

Tags: margins, koma-script, titles

The `scrbook` class calculates margins automatically. For the title page of a book, I would like no margins at all, so that the text would be centered properly.

How can I disable all margins for the title page, and then reactivate them for the inside of the book?

Comment: Just FYI, the title page **is** inside the book, and should have normal margins. A book cover is *not* produced by the `\maketitle` macro – Koma script recommends (correctly) that a book cover resides in a separate document.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Konrad. I was not mentioning the book cover, the title page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package offers you the `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` commands to change page dimensions for some part of the document.

I would suggest, however, a different approach: design the title page as a different standalone document, with the desired page dimensions, and then use the [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package to include this title page in your book.

Comment: Right, I think the pdfpages approach is probably better.

Comment: @Raphink: since you use a KOMA-Script class, perhaps check out the [`titlepage` package solution of KOMA-Script](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page/25408#25408) below too.

Answer (score 10):

For the record, the solution I chose uses `pdfpages`:

```
% No margins at all
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize=pdftex,DIV=100]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\input{title}
\end{document}
```

I build this document with `pdftex` first, and I replaced:

```
\input{title.tex}
```

with

```
\includepdf{title_standalone.pdf}
```

in my main document.

Comment: You can change `DIV` inside a document using `\KOMAoptions`. So you do not need an external document.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the new `titlepage` package of KOMA-Script and its environment `fullsizetitle`. This gives you a page without any margin.

- Download: http://www.komascript.de/files/titlepage.tds_.zip
- German documentation: http://www.komascript.de/titlepage

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlepage}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullsizetitle}
\blindtext[13]
\end{fullsizetitle}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page without margins]

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. In the meanwhile, I redesigned my title page in Inskape because it was a bit too complex, so I'm sticking to PDF inclusion, but I'll keep that in mind :-)

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz : May I ask you what happened to the `fullsizetitle`-command? I fear it has not been implemented into KOMA, has it?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Did you use the `titlepage` package?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz It cannot be found on my system (mactex). It seems that it is not part of the distribution. But why?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz : I mean the `fullsizetitle`-command (and maybe also the rest of `titlepage`) is so useful that it should be part of KOMA without having to install a new package. Or is it still in alpha/beta?

Comment: @ClintEastwood As it's also a collection of ready-to-use title pages. it's good to have it separate. Some commonly usable commands could go to the main classes, that's true. It's just not the case now, but could be encouraged to the author.

Answer (score 5):

I had same same issue and discovered, that for more recent versions of KOMA-Script (from 3.12 on), there is the option `titlepage=firstiscover` present to achieve exactly, what you were looking for.

Just use it as option for your documentclass:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=firstiscover]{scrbook}
```

With

```
\renewcommand*{\coverpagetopmargin}{0mm}
\renewcommand*{\coverpageleftmargin}{0mm}
\renewcommand*{\coverpagerightmargin}{0mm}
\renewcommand*{\coverpagebottommargin}{0mm}
```

the margins can be removed or likewise set as intended.

Comment: I used that yesterday as well :-) [Different margins in title and chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223765)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for standard title pages automatically generated with the `\maketitle` command. Title pages defined in the `titlepage` environment are unaffected.

Comment: +1 Made my day!