# How to avoid geometry affecting the first page?

Tags: margins, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove margins for title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page)

I'm using the package `geometry` to set the margins of my report, according to my needs (with a particularly wide right margin). However, it seems that it affects the front page as well, that is, the title of the report is not centered anymore in its page.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: See my answer to this question: [Remove margins for title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20177/3954).

Answer (score 5):

The [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) provides the `\newgeometry` command, which allows you to change the page layout at any time. So if you want to leave the front page alone, you could try something like this.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\title{My report}
\author{A N Other}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newgeometry{rmargin=15cm}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to see the changed and unchanged margins, even on relatively empty pages, you can load `geometry` with the `showframe` option, which will add lines indicating the margins.

Comment: Many thanks Ian, that solved my problem perfectly well.
Doncherry, thank you for the tip and the editing !