# Make titlepage one-sided (centered) while all other pages are two-sided

Tags: koma-script, titles, double-sided

I am using scrbook to write a small paper. I am trying to create a title page which displays its contents (title, author, institution) with a one-sided layout, while all other pages should use a two-sided layout. I couldn't come up with an easy solution. I use the following macro to define my title page:

```
\newenvironment{tpage}[3]{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \title{#2}
    \subtitle{#3}
    \date{City, den \today}
    \author{#1}

    \titlehead {
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
        Institution\\
      \end{minipage}
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
          \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{somelogo.pdf}
        \end{flushright}
      \end{minipage}
      \hrule
    }

    \maketitle
  \end{titlepage}
}{}
```

I'd like to stick with that macro if possible. Is there a simple command to switch from a onesided layout to a twosided layout? Something like `\oneside`? I didn't find such a command. My documentclass is configured as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
, 12pt
, titlepage
, toc=listofnumbered
, bibliography=totoc
]{scrbook}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove margins for title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please provide full examples.

Do you use the package `geometry`?

Here a solution with `KOMA`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
, 12pt
, titlepage
, toc=listofnumbered
, bibliography=totoc
,  demo
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newenvironment{tpage}[3]{%
\KOMAoptions{twoside = false}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \title{#2}
    \subtitle{#3}
    \date{City, den \today}
    \author{#1}

    \titlehead {
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
        Institution\\
      \end{minipage}
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
          \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{somelogo.pdf}
        \end{flushright}
      \end{minipage}
      \hrule
    }

    \maketitle
  \end{titlepage}
\KOMAoptions{twoside}
}{}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}
\begin{document}

\tpage{Author}{TITLE}{SUBTITLE}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using the `fullsizetitle` of the [`titlepage`](http://www.komascript.de/files/titlepage.tds_.zip) package of KOMA-Script you could remove all margins and produce a symmetric layout, by `\addmargin` or `\centering` for example.

Starting with my answer in [Remove margins for title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page/25408#25408), here's a simple example with a symmetric title page and asymmetric following pages:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlepage}
\title{Test}
\author{Stefan}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullsizetitle}
\centering
\vspace*{3cm}
\Huge Title\par
\bigskip
\Large Author\par
\today\par
\end{fullsizetitle}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```