# \twosides in KOMA - Why is my titlepage not centered

Tags: titles, koma-script, best-practices, double-sided

I'm using `scrbook` with the `twosides`option, and `BCOR=10mm`. The title page, being an odd page, has a large margin on the right, and a small margin on the left.

I'm currently using the following to make the title page centered:

```
\KOMAoptions{twoside = false}
\maketitle
\KOMAoptions{twoside = true}
```

However, I'm getting warnings that I should not do change the `typearea`.

Is the above workaround unhealthy for getting the right input dimensions?

More importantly: When should one use a (one-sided) cover page, and when should one use a (two-sided) title page?

This question is related to [Centered title page in twoside report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57158/centered-title-page-in-twoside-report) and [Make titlepage one-sided (centered) while all other pages are two-sided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25405/make-titlepage-one-sided-centered-while-all-other-pages-are-two-sided?rq=1) , but is rather interested in the technical and layout details.

Comment: The question "When should you use it?" admits of no objective answer. When you think it looks better! Obviously only if you have a centered title page. Then the decision whether to center on the paper or the text-block seems to vary from publisher to publisher: a glance at a few books on my shelf shows both.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't show us a MWE so I have to guess.

If you make your title page with KOMA-Scripts class `scrbook` and if you use `\maketitle` the title page is **included** in the standard type area. For a double sided book you have different margins, the outer margin is wider, the inner smaller.  That's the reason why you get no centered title page.

If you want a centered title page without changing typearea use environment `titlepage` and package [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos). With `textpos` you can move text on a special point and at last you can build a centered title page by your own.

An alternative would be to create a second `tex` file, onesided, and use the resulting title page from this second file.

Comment: Markus Kohm provides a package for this: `titlepage` with the environment `fullsizetitle`: http://www.komascript.de/node/1216