# Too high footer on (custom) title page in scrartcl

Tags: spacing, titles, koma-script

I wanna have custom title page in my document created with `scrartcl` class. I'm using `titlepage` environment (which I believe sets `thispagestyle=empty`). Still I have rather high footer: just as in normal text (which of course looks ok because it has page numbers in a footer).

What are preffered ways to have the footer on title page smaller? I'm thinking principally of two approaches: 1) `footheight` might be discarded (i.e. = 0), 2) last portion ot text (city and date) might become part of the footer.

My code is as follows.

```
\documentclass [fontsize=14pt, paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc] {scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\parindent=1.25cm
\frenchspacing

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} % recalculate text area as recommended in KOMA-guide

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
  %
  %\thispagestyle {empty}
  %
  \begin {center}
    %
    [Federal Authority]
    %
    \vskip 15pt
    %
    My University
    %
    \vskip 15pt
    %
    My Department
    %
    \vskip 15pt
    %
    My chair
  \end {center}
  %
  \vspace* {\fill}
  %
  \begin {center}
    %
    Me
    %
    %
    \vskip 18pt
    %
    Title
    %
  \end {center}
  %
  \vspace {\fill}
  %
  \begin {center}
    %
    City \\
    %
    Date
    %                Here will be huge vertical space for some reason
  \end {center}
  %
  \end{titlepage}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Which results in
[image]

Comment: Please also have a look at [Different margins in title and chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223765)

Comment: @Johannes_B interesting! I read on `firstiscover` (mentioned by you there) in KOMA-guide. They say that change of geometry for title is not recommended. Can you suggest, how can I just set footer for City/Date? (Second approach mentioned in my question.)

Comment: As the title (inner) is part of the dicument, it should follow the same type block. The left and right margins should not be touched, as the tille would look displaced horizontally. Vertically, this isn't really an issue and you can savely do `enlargethispage` as suggested by egreg. It is the simplest and most practical approach.

Comment: The cover on the other hand would be the part that is visible getting the book off the shelf without opening it. There, left and right margins are a different matter, as, for example, the binding correction does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the package `scrlayer` (part of the KOMA-Script bundle) and define your a special pagestyle for the titlepage.

```
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foot,
  foreground,
  contents={%
    \raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[\layerheight][0pt]{%
      \parbox[b]{\layerwidth}{\centering City\par Date}}%
  }
]{titlepage.foot.fg}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepage.foot.fg}
```

and

```
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
```

[image]

Code (with the additional changes by @egreg):

```
\documentclass [fontsize=14pt, paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc] {scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe} %%% just for the example

\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\parindent=1.25cm
\frenchspacing

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} % recalculate text area as recommended in KOMA-guide

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foot,
  foreground,
  contents={%
    \raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[\layerheight][0pt]{%
      \parbox[b]{\layerwidth}{\centering City\par Date}}%
  }
]{titlepage.foot.fg}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepage.foot.fg}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\centering
[Federal Authority]

\vspace{15pt}

My University

\vspace{15pt}

My Department

\vspace{15pt}

My chair

\vspace{\fill}

Me

\vspace{18pt}

Title

\vspace{\fill}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

---

Note, that the code above needs KOMA-Script Version 3.14 or newer. The current version on CTAN, in TeX Live and MiKTeX is version 3.15 and the up to date major release is 3.16.

Unfortunately `Overleaf` still uses the old KOMA-Script Version 3.12. (The command `\KOMAScriptVersion` prints the used version in the document.) So with `Overleaf` you have to change the code

```
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foot,
  foreground,
  contents={%
    \raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[\layerheight][0pt]{%
      \parbox[b]{\layerwidth}{\centering\titlepagefoot}}%
  }
]{titlepage.foot.fg}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepage.foot.fg}
\newcommand\titlepagefoot{City\par Date}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This is more thorough solution that one give by @egreg, so I accept it.

Comment: Oops, I didn't test then. In overleaf.com this is rejected with “Paragraph ended before \\DeclareNewLayer was complete” and point to \par.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Overleaf uses the old KOMA-Script version 3.12. I have updated my answer and added a suggestion that will also work on overleaf.com.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\enlargethispage`. I also changed somewhat your code: better using `\vspace` than `\vskip` and just a `\centering` declaration.

```
\documentclass [fontsize=14pt, paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc] {scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe} %%% just for the example

\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\frenchspacing

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} % recalculate text area as recommended in KOMA-guide

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\centering
\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip} % <------------ adjust at will

[Federal Authority]

\vspace{15pt}

My University

\vspace{15pt}

My Department

\vspace{15pt}

My chair

\vspace{\fill}

Me

\vspace{18pt}

Title

\vspace{\fill}

City

Date

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. Visually the result is close to what I really desire. Technically it is not that beautiful. So I +1d this but wait if someone suggests more consistent solution for a while.

Comment: Why not also changing the `parindent`? ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B changing for what?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn `\setlength{\parindent}{1.25em}`. LaTeX syntax `;-)`

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks! I've just fixed it in my file thanks to you.