# scrbook pagemargins with titlepage

Tags: margins, titles, koma-script, double-sided, scrbook

I've finished writing my Bachelor's thesis and want it printed like a book. So I need to make the inner margins a bit broader than the outer ones ("BCOR"). Additionally, I want my chapters always to start on right pages.
My minimal example causes the outer margins to be broader than the inner ones. (Titlepage will be a right page, so the left margin should be broader and so on...)

How can I get that fixed, any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Katharina

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper, BCOR=8mm, DIV=12, openright]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000 \displaywidowpenalty=10000
\interlinepenalty5000
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\large
Abschlussarbeit im Bachelorstudiengang Physik
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}



\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

Visualization techniques are at the heart of research in the fields of life sciences. Hence, fluorescence microscopy is an essential and commonly used tool for investigations on biological structures and processes.

\chapter{Theory}

During his work on optical instruments, Ernst Abbe discovered in 1873 that the size of the focal spot cannot be determined by taking into account only aberrations and geometrical beam paths, but that it is limited by diffraction.

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a missunderstanding. In a book the outer margin has nearly the same wide as the distance between the text on the even page and the text on the odd page. So the outer margin should be twice as wide as the inner margin. See the documentation of package `typearea` in the [scrguien.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) or the [scrguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf)

Comment: If you really want different margins for the titlepage, cause you don't talk about the titlepage *inside* the book, but the cover ... have a look at [Different margins in title and chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223765)

Comment: Please also have a look at [Welche Seitenzahl hat das Inhaltsverzeichnis](http://golatex.de/welche-seitenzahl-hat-das-inhaltsverzeichnis-t13474.html)

Comment: The given example works as expected and documented. The question seems to be due to a missunderstanding of the documented material in section 2 of the KOMA manual. As there was never *any* feedback by the unregistered OP, i vtc as unclear.