# Add single empty page before the cover page of the dissertation

Tags: double-sided, book-design, books

I would like to add a single page before the cover page so that the cover page starts with a larger margin on the left, thus placed on the right hand side of the book.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\begin{document}
\null\newpage
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{0.5cm}        
{\large\textbf{Title}} \\      
\vspace{3cm}
 DISSERTATION \\ [1em] 
 zur Erlangung des akademischen Grades \\ [1em]
 Dr. rer. nat. \\ 
 im the Institute of \\ [1em]
 so and so \\
 from the university \\ [1em]
 von \\             
\end{center}  
\vspace{1cm}
%\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want the title page to be on right side of your PDF (such as the 3rd, 5th, etc. pages), you need to check in your viewer and select the option "double". If you really want your page 1 to be blank, what about inserting `\null\newpage` just after `\begin{document}`? But if its only margin-related, have you considered using the `twoside` option in `\documentclass[options]{class}`?

Comment: @ebo I editted my question with a dummy example. If you compile it you will see that the title page has always a larger margin to the right.. I want it on the left ...

Comment: if you use `\usepackage{showframe}` you'll see that you're issue is because of the margin. Thus, you could have a look at [Different margins for title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/different-margins-for-title-page), [change title page margins ONLY without packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/different-margins-for-title-page), and if you use a KOMA class: [Remove margins for title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page).

Comment: Why not use `openright` as an option in `\documentclass`?

Comment: You may also define a style for the `titlepage` with .e.g., `fancyhdr` package; Or use package `geometry` package along with the command `\geometry` so that you will have a different geometry for the `titlepage` and another for the rest of the document.

Comment: The OP confuses right hand and left hand pages and the margin settings. The question is asked on false premises and hence (imho) unclear. I vote to close as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe,left=7cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \large\textbf{\thepage}\par
        This is a right hand page
        \vfill
    \end{center}  
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```