# Change title page margins and BCOR

Tags: margins, titles

I have the following main document, which is normally a lot longer. In general, I have the title page in a separate document and include this via `\include{titlepage}`. How can I change the margins and BCOR for the title page only, so that the title sits in the centre of the page?
I tried `titlepage=firstiscover`,`titlepage=true`, and `\begin{fullsizetitle}` as recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page) which all did not work. I also tried to compile the title page separately and include the pdf, but this produces a clash with pgfplots.

Thanks for your support

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
                twoside,
                openright,
                DIV=10,
                BCOR=10mm, 
                headsepline,
                fontsize=11pt,captions=tableheading]
                {scrreprt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
         \begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
        \Huge
        {\textbf{Title}}\\

        \vspace{1cm}
        \Large
         {Subtitle}\\

        \vspace{3cm}
        \normalsize
        {University of ...\\}
        \end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
        \vspace{3cm}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that the `center` environment might add unwanted space. If you're in an environment already, it is advised to use `\centering` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titlepage=firstiscover` option does only work on `\maketitle` not on the `titlepage` environment. The following copies some of the code used in `\maketitle` if the option `titlepage=firstiscover` was used and inserts it into your `titlepage`. I've added a `\rule` just so one sees that the margins are indeed correct. I've also added some dummy content so that you can see that the margins are restored after the `titlepage` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               twoside,
               openright,
               DIV=10,
               BCOR=10mm, 
               headsepline,
               fontsize=11pt,
               captions=tableheading,
               ]
               {scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\titlepagegeometry
  {%
    \begingroup
    \edef\titlepagerestore
      {%
        \noexpand\clearpage
        \endgroup
        \global\@colht\the\@colht
        \global\@colroom\the\@colroom
        \global\vsize\the\vsize
      }%
    \topmargin=\dimexpr\coverpagetopmargin-1in\relax
    \oddsidemargin=\dimexpr\coverpageleftmargin-1in\relax
    \evensidemargin=\dimexpr\coverpageleftmargin-1in\relax
    \textwidth=%
      \dimexpr\paperwidth-\coverpageleftmargin-\coverpagerightmargin\relax
    \headheight=0pt
    \headsep=0pt
    \footskip=\baselineskip
    \@colht=\textheight
    \@colroom=\textheight
    \vsize=\textheight
    \columnwidth=\textwidth
    \hsize=\columnwidth
    \linewidth=\hsize
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy content

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \titlepagegeometry
  \centering
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \Huge \textbf{Title}\\
  \rule{\textwidth}{5pt}

  \vspace{1cm}
  \Large Subtitle\\

  \vspace{3cm}
  \normalsize University of ...\\
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \vspace{3cm}
  \titlepagerestore
\end{titlepage}

\duckument
\end{document}
```

The resulting title page:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!